# I got undefined dataset, when getting data attribute in html

Tags: javascript

I have this code in html,

```
<ul id="locationSelect" style="visibility: visible;">
  <li class="location-select" data-num="9"></li>
  <li class="location-select" data-num="9"></li>
  <li class="location-select" data-num="7"></li>
  <li class="location-select" data-num="6"></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to get the value of `data-num` attribute when the user click on any `<li>` element using pure javascript.

Here the code for javascript so far.

```
let locSel = document.getElementById('locationSelect').getElementsByClassName('location-select');

for(var i=0; i < locSel.length; i++) {
    locSel[i].onclick = function() {
      let markerNum = locSel[i].dataset.num;
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
    };
}
```

Given that code, I got undefined, on the part of `locSel[i]` and then got stack (I dont know the right spelling for this word stack). I have know idea.

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let locSel = document.getElementById('locationSelect').getElementsByClassName('location-select');

for(let i=0; i < locSel.length; i++) {
    locSel[i].onclick = function() {
      let markerNum = locSel[i].dataset.num;
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
    };
}
```

Comment: why is it not working using var on for? instead it work using let?

Comment: let (respects the block scope)

Answer (score 2):

When your `onclick`  handler is called, `i` is equal to 4, so `locSel[i]` will always be `undefined`. This is because you declared `i` as a  `var` and the same variable will live and be accessed through all your code.

In order to have `i` get a new binding for every iteration of the loop, use `let` instead of `var`:

```
for(let i=0; i < locSel.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Check this to know the differenve between `let` and `var`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav

Answer (score 0):

```
const imgRef = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");

const observer = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
    entry.target.src = imgRef.dataset.src;
  });
  console.log(entries);
};

const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver(observer, {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
});
imgRef.forEach((image) => {
  imgObserver.observe(image);
});
```

In My Case i am trying to lazy load images using data-src But It is not defined i dont know if i have defined imgRef correctly or not